# How to use two pointer to define a string isPalindrome?

Tags: c

`Input: s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"`

`Output: true`

`Explanation: "amanaplanacanalpanama" is a palindrome.`

```
bool isPalindrome(char * s){
    if(strlen(s) == 0) return true;

    int m  = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if(isalnum(s[i])) s[m++] = tolower(s[i]);
    int i = 0;
    while(i<m)
        if(s[i++] != s[--m]) return false;

    return true;
}
```

My code's running time is 173ms. My instructor suggested me to use two pointers to improve the performance and memory usage, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @Shovo Please don't edit out parts of the question. The note on memory usage is part of the question. Whether or not it's a legitimate concern can be addressed in an answer or a comment.

Comment: Tip: You don't need to go through the whole string, you can stop in the middle.

Comment: I'm going to write up a proper answer, but I wonder how the runtime would change due to other changes. E.g., only calculate `strlen(s)` once (rather than `strlen(s) + 1` times), sprinkle in some `const`, etc. Maybe the compiler optimizes it to the equivalent, but I would look into those sorts of things even without changing the algorithm at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just position the two pointers like this

```
char* first = someString;
char* end = someString + strlen(s) - 1;
```

Now for it to be a palindrome what `first` and `end` point to must be the same

```
e.g. char someString[] = "1331";
```

So you in the first iteration *first == *last i.e. '1'

Now move the pointers towards each other until there is nothing left to compare or when they differ

```
++first, --end;

now *first and *last point to '3'
```

and so on, check if they are pointing to the same or have passed each other it is a palindrome.

Something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int palindrome(char* str)
{
  char* start = str;
  char* end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  for (; start < end; ++start, --end )
  {
      if (*start != *end)
      {
          return 0;
      }
  }
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("palindrome: %d\n", palindrome("1331"));
    printf("palindrome: %d\n", palindrome("132331"));
    printf("palindrome: %d\n", palindrome("74547"));

    return 0;
}
```

You should add error checks, there are no error checks in the function.

Comment: Though this is a good approach, it's worth making a note about confusing names. The `s` in your answer does not align with the `s` in the question. The palindrome check there first strips non-alphanumeric characters, meaning the `last` pointer can't be calculated by adding `strlen(s)`.

Comment: Is that possible to post the whole edited code? It will be very helpful for me and other beginners to understand the whole process better. I appreciate it .

Comment: @MingfengLi sure

Answer (score 0):

> My code's running time is 173ms. My instructor suggested me to use two pointers to improve the performance and memory usage, but I have no idea where to start.

It's already running in O(n) so you cannot reduce the time complexity (except for the iterative call to `strlen`, see below), although there are some room for improving performance.

Your function does not declare any arrays, and only use a few variables and the memory usage does not depend at all on input size. The memory usage is already O(1) and very low, so it's not a real concern.

But if you want to do it with pointers, here is one:

```
bool isPalindrome(char * s){
    char *end = s + strlen(s);
    char *a = s;
    char *b = end-1;
    
    while(true) {
        
        // Skip characters that's not alphanumeric
        while( a != end && !isalnum(*a) ) a++;
        while( b != s && !isalnum(*b) ) b--;

        // We're done when we have passed the middle
        if(b < a) break;
       
        // Perform the check
        if(tolower(*a) != tolower(*b)) return false;

        // Step to next character
        a++;
        b--;
    }

    return true;
}
```

When it comes to performance, your code has two issues, none of which gets solved by pointers. First one is that you're calling `strlen` for each iteration. The second is that you don't need to loop through the whole array, because that's checking it twice.

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
```

should be

```
size_t len = strlen(s);
for(size_t i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
```

Another remark I have on your code is that it changes the input string. That's not necessary. If I have a function that is called `isPalindrome` I'd expect it to ONLY check if the string is a palindrome or not. IMO, the signature should be `bool isPalindrome(const char * s)`

Comment: ==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000072 at pc 0x562272a15546 bp 0x7ffea9aaa0b0 sp 0x7ffea9aaa0a0. Your code has the buffer overflow problem, and only passed 2 tests.

Comment: @MingfengLi Think I fixed it now

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly now. I am still curious why we need to increment a and decrement b at the end of the while loop.

Comment: @MingfengLi Because otherwise you would just stand still

Comment: @MingfengLi Does that answer your question? Or what was unclear?

Comment: Yea, I got it now! We have to compare the characters, one from the front and one from the back. Thank you!